# How we can validate/identify two SQL queries whether data is matching from both the queries output or not in SAP HANA Studio?

Tags: sql, hana

I have two SQL queries, one is query on top of reporting Calculation View (CV) and the other is a query on the base CV of reported CV. Now, I need to compare both the outputs are matching or not.

Can anyone suggest the SQL query for this?

This is my query which I'm trying to get the output in SAP HANA Studio:

```
Select *   
From 
    (Select X, Y  
     From Table1 
     Minus 
     Select X,Y 
     From Table2);
```

Is there any other suggestions please?

Many thanks in advance

Regards
Chandrababu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my options:

**First:**

```
 SELECT * FROM  
    (
        SELECT "X", "Y" FROM Table1
        EXCEPT
        SELECT "X", "Y" FROM Table2
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT "X", "Y" FROM Table2
        EXCEPT
        SELECT "X", "Y" FROM Table1
    );
```

**Second:**

```
SELECT "X", "Y" FROM
(
    SELECT "X", "Y" FROM Table1
     UNION ALL
    SELECT "X", "Y" FROM Table2
)
GROUP BY
    "X", "Y"
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1;
```

**Third:**

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(T1."X",T2."X") AS "X",
    IFNULL(T1."Y",T2."Y") AS "Y"
FROM
    Table1 T1
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1."X" = T2."X" AND T1."Y" = T2."Y" 
WHERE
    T1."X" IS NULL OR T2."X" IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank You Konza for your valuable suggestions!!

Comment: If this resolves your question, please accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using FULL OUTER JOIN, it is possible to display common items as well as differences of both tables from other

Here is the query

```
select table1.*, table2.* 
from table1
full outer join table2
    on table1.x = table2.x and
       table1.y = table2.y;
```

And the outcome is here

[image]

Comment: Thank You Eralper for your valuable suggestions!!